# cecil: Instruction.Operand types corresponding to Instruction.OpCode.Code value

Tags: c#, mono, cil, il, mono.cecil

Is there any documentation or is there a part of the cecil source code that I can consult to get a comprehensive view of which `Operand` types cecil will use for a given `Code` value? Eg: I can glean from `MethodBodyRocks` that `Ldloc` takes an `Operand` of type `VariableDefinition`, but I haven't been able to track down this down for some of the other instruction codes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can look at the definition of every OpCode in the [OpCodes.cs](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/blob/master/Mono.Cecil.Cil/OpCodes.cs) file.

E.g. for **Ldloc** you would see **OperandType.InlineVar**

Answer (score 21):

To add to poupou's answer, [OpCodes.cs](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/blob/master/Mono.Cecil.Cil/OpCodes.cs) shows which `OperandType` gets assigned for each instruction Code. Using this `OperandType` you can consult [CodeReader.ReadOperand](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/blob/master/Mono.Cecil.Cil/CodeReader.cs) to see how these `OperandType`s are used to determine which concrete object type is constructed. Also note that `CodeReader.ReadCode` uses `CodeReader.ResolveBranches` to transform some operands from instruction offsets into `Instruction` objects before returning.

I created this table which was a lot more convenient then digging through the source every time (anything not covered in this table should have an InlineNone OperandType):

```
Instruction.OpCode.Code|Instruction.OpCode.OperandType|Instruction.Operand class
Ldarg_S                |ShortInlineArg                |ParameterDefinition
Ldarga_S               |ShortInlineArg                |ParameterDefinition
Starg_S                |ShortInlineArg                |ParameterDefinition
Ldloc_S                |ShortInlineVar                |VariableDefinition
Ldloca_S               |ShortInlineVar                |VariableDefinition
Stloc_S                |ShortInlineVar                |VariableDefinition
Ldc_I4_S               |ShortInlineI                  |sbyte <===== NOTE: special case
Ldc_I4                 |InlineI                       |int32
Ldc_I8                 |InlineI8                      |int64
Ldc_R4                 |ShortInlineR                  |single
Ldc_R8                 |InlineR                       |float (64 bit)
Jmp                    |InlineMethod                  |MethodReference
Call                   |InlineMethod                  |MethodReference
Calli                  |InlineSig                     |CallSite
Br_S                   |ShortInlineBrTarget           |Instruction
Brfalse_S              |ShortInlineBrTarget           |Instruction
Brtrue_S               |ShortInlineBrTarget           |Instruction
Beq_S                  |ShortInlineBrTarget           |Instruction
Bge_S                  |ShortInlineBrTarget           |Instruction
Bgt_S                  |ShortInlineBrTarget           |Instruction
Ble_S                  |ShortInlineBrTarget           |Instruction
Blt_S                  |ShortInlineBrTarget           |Instruction
Bne_Un_S               |ShortInlineBrTarget           |Instruction
Bge_Un_S               |ShortInlineBrTarget           |Instruction
Bgt_Un_S               |ShortInlineBrTarget           |Instruction
Ble_Un_S               |ShortInlineBrTarget           |Instruction
Blt_Un_S               |ShortInlineBrTarget           |Instruction
Br                     |InlineBrTarget                |Instruction
Brfalse                |InlineBrTarget                |Instruction
Brtrue                 |InlineBrTarget                |Instruction
Beq                    |InlineBrTarget                |Instruction
Bge                    |InlineBrTarget                |Instruction
Bgt                    |InlineBrTarget                |Instruction
Ble                    |InlineBrTarget                |Instruction
Blt                    |InlineBrTarget                |Instruction
Bne_Un                 |InlineBrTarget                |Instruction
Bge_Un                 |InlineBrTarget                |Instruction
Bgt_Un                 |InlineBrTarget                |Instruction
Ble_Un                 |InlineBrTarget                |Instruction
Blt_Un                 |InlineBrTarget                |Instruction
Switch                 |InlineSwitch                  |Instruction array
Callvirt               |InlineMethod                  |MethodReference
Cpobj                  |InlineType                    |TypeReference
Ldobj                  |InlineType                    |TypeReference
Ldstr                  |InlineString                  |string
Newobj                 |InlineMethod                  |MethodReference
Castclass              |InlineType                    |TypeReference
Isinst                 |InlineType                    |TypeReference
Unbox                  |InlineType                    |TypeReference
Ldfld                  |InlineField                   |FieldReference
Ldflda                 |InlineField                   |FieldReference
Stfld                  |InlineField                   |FieldReference
Ldsfld                 |InlineField                   |FieldReference
Ldsflda                |InlineField                   |FieldReference
Stsfld                 |InlineField                   |FieldReference
Stobj                  |InlineType                    |TypeReference
Box                    |InlineType                    |TypeReference
Newarr                 |InlineType                    |TypeReference
Ldelema                |InlineType                    |TypeReference
Ldelem_Any             |InlineType                    |TypeReference
Stelem_Any             |InlineType                    |TypeReference
Unbox_Any              |InlineType                    |TypeReference
Refanyval              |InlineType                    |TypeReference
Mkrefany               |InlineType                    |TypeReference
Ldtoken                |InlineTok                     |IMetadataTokenProvider
Leave                  |InlineBrTarget                |Instruction
Leave_S                |ShortInlineBrTarget           |Instruction
Ldftn                  |InlineMethod                  |MethodReference
Ldvirtftn              |InlineMethod                  |MethodReference
Ldarg                  |InlineArg                     |ParameterDefinition
Ldarga                 |InlineArg                     |ParameterDefinition
Starg                  |InlineArg                     |ParameterDefinition
Ldloc                  |InlineVar                     |VariableDefinition
Ldloca                 |InlineVar                     |VariableDefinition
Stloc                  |InlineVar                     |VariableDefinition
Unaligned              |ShortInlineI                  |byte
Initobj                |InlineType                    |TypeReference
Constrained            |InlineType                    |TypeReference
No                     |ShortInlineI                  |byte
Sizeof                 |InlineType                    |TypeReference
```